# INotifyPropertyChanged with an Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, inotifypropertychanged

still new to C# and WPF and well I want to use an Enum but I can't figure out how to use it with OnPropertyChanged

```
public enum _status
{
    AuthRequired, AuthAttempted, AuthReceived, AuthError, AuthSuccessful
}
```

this doesn't work:

```
public enum AuthStatus
{
  get { return _status; }
  set { ..... }
}
```

I know the solution is going to be very simple but i haven't found anything when I looked on google.. any help?

Comment: The solution is not simple. It is the same whether enum or not - because INotifyPropertyChanged cares not at all about what the property holds. It publishes the NAME of the property, not the content. So, read any tutorial and a book and work through them. and INotifyPropertyChanged is not a WPF thing - it is core .NET.

Comment: Forget about enum. How'll you implement for other types? Exactly same way..

Comment: pretty much i just wanted to use it as a way to keep track of the status of what i'm doing.. like first step, second step etc.  then i'd like to use that property to set a WPF data trigger change to change a  label or something.. these are my thoughts initially anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This simply will not work.

Part of the problem is that an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx), by definition, cannot set values, and for the normal use of enums you would never want to. This is simply how enums work.

Now, if your *property* in your model or viewmodel is an enum type, you can easily declare it as a property and raise property changes as with any other type.

```
private Status _status
public enum Status
{
    AuthRequired, AuthAttempted, AuthReceived, AuthError, AuthSuccessful
}

public Status Status
{
    get { return _status; }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  that makes alot of sense and will use a different data type.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to mark an accepted answer when you're satisfied you have the right one!

Comment: doesn't let you until 5 minutes =P

Comment: Well, that's interesting. ThingsLearnedToday++;

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare an `enum` as a property. Your code needs to be:

```
private _status _myStatus;
public _status AuthStatus
{
  get { return _myStatus; }
  set 
  { 
     _myStatus = value;
     NotifyPropertyChanged("AuthStatus")
  }
}
```

Writing `public enum _status` declares a new type called `_status` (note this isn't a very good name for a type, since it looks like a private data member). You then need to declare a property and field **of this type** that you can then run NotifyPropertyChanged on.